# How to minimize code when using sqlalchemy query and pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to upgrade my query code by modernizing it.

My old code (bellow). First query joins two tables and selects the rating for each song title together with artist for title and the second gets the genres for each title (association table is used):

```
items = []
query = db.session.query(Rating, Song).filter(Rating.id==Song.id).all()
for x in query:
    dic = {
        "rating": x[0],
        "title": x[1].title,
        "artist": x[1].artist,
        "genre": Genre.query.filter(Genre.songs.any(title=x[1].title)).all(),
        }
    items.append(dic)
```

My cleaner code. I use pandas dataframes now instead of dictionaries. This gives me the error `ArgumentError: SQL expression element or literal value expected, got somethingsomething`

```
query = db.session.query(Rating, Song).filter(Rating.id==Song.id).all()
df = pd.DataFrame(query, columns=["rating", "title"])
for item in df.title:
    df['genre'] = (Genre.query.filter(Genre.songs.any(title=item)).all())
```

- How do I get this to work?
- Are there more effiecient ways of coding this?

Complete error produced

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)
   1194         try:
-> 1195             meth = statement._execute_on_connection
   1196         except AttributeError as err:

AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute '_execute_on_connection'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ObjectNotExecutableError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-99ffacdf2d91> in <module>
      1 query = db.session.query(Rating, Song).filter(Rating.id==Song.id)
----> 2 df = pd.read_sql_query(query, db.engine)
      3 df

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize)
    381         coerce_float=coerce_float,
    382         parse_dates=parse_dates,
--> 383         chunksize=chunksize,
    384     )
    385 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, parse_dates, params, chunksize)
   1292         args = _convert_params(sql, params)
   1293 
-> 1294         result = self.execute(*args)
   1295         columns = result.keys()
   1296 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1160     def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
   1161         """Simple passthrough to SQLAlchemy connectable"""
-> 1162         return self.connectable.execution_options().execute(*args, **kwargs)
   1163 
   1164     def read_table(

<string> in execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py in warned(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    388         if not skip_warning:
    389             _warn_with_version(message, version, wtype, stacklevel=3)
--> 390         return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    391 
    392     doc = func.__doc__ is not None and func.__doc__ or ""

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)
   3036         """
   3037         connection = self.connect(close_with_result=True)
-> 3038         return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
   3039 
   3040     @util.deprecated_20(

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)
   1196         except AttributeError as err:
   1197             util.raise_(
-> 1198                 exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(statement), replace_context=err
   1199             )
   1200         else:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    209 
    210         try:
--> 211             raise exception
    212         finally:
    213             # credit to

ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: <flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object at 0x000001CBC5F14A48>
```

Comment: Try removing `.all()` from the end of your `query = …` statement and then do `df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)`

Comment: Why am I adding engine there? I thought the use of sqlalchemy was to place all the connection requirements in the background

Comment: The second argument to [.read_sql_query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) needs to be a SQLAlchemy connectable (Engine or Connection) or a SQLite DBAPI connection object.

Comment: I tried df = pd.read_sql_query(query, db.engine) and got an error. I don't think I understand what the enginge part is supposed to be

Comment: If you're using flask-sqlalchemy then `db.engine` should be appropriate for the second argument to `.read_sql_query()`. [This code](https://pastebin.com/qNn3TKvY) works fine for me.

Comment: I see that you have used db = SQLAlchemy(app) while I have used db.init_app(app). I don't know what the difference is but maybe this is why my code doesn't work

Comment: "I tried df = pd.read_sql_query(query, db.engine) and got an error." – Please edit your question to show that statement and the *complete* error it produces.

Comment: I have added the error as requested

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create just one query to return all the data you need in one go, where the grouping of Genres is done uisng the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#group_concat) function:

```
query = (
    db.session
    .query(
        Rating.rating,
        Song.title,
        Song.artist,
        db.func.GROUP_CONCAT(Genre.category, ", ").label("genres")
    )
    .select_from(Song)
    .where(Rating.id == Song.id)
    .join(Genre, Song.genres)
    .group_by(
        Rating.rating,
        Song.title,
        Song.artist,
    )
)
```

Then use the pandas method to get it into a dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query.statement, db.engine)
```

Where `print(df)` should produce something like this:

```
   rating    title artist            genres
0     2.0  title 2  art-2               pop
1     3.0  title 3  art-3         rock, pop
2     4.0  title 4  art-3             other
3     5.0  title 5  art-4  rock, pop, other
```